# Java read from a textfile and get all values inbetween parentheses

Tags: java

I've got the following code which reads my text file and gets the value inside the parentheses.

```
String content = new Scanner(new File(hello.txt)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
double value = Double.parseDouble(content.substring(content.indexOf("(") + 1, content.indexOf(")")));
System.out.println(value);
```

How can I change it so if the text file has multiple parentheses, it prints them all?

A sample text file would look something like this:

```
334.43 (0.03037)
655.32 (1.203)
734234.5948 (232.4358)
78764.342 (564.342342)
```

So I want the output to be:

```
0.03037
1.203
232.4358
564.342342
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase 'regular expression'?

Comment: Store a new Scanner instance and keep getting the next line and getting a certain substring?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and read the file line by line

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(hello.txt)).useDelimiter("\\Z");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String content = sc.nextLine();
        double value = Double.parseDouble(content.substring(content.indexOf("(") + 1, content.indexOf(")")));
        System.out.println(value); 
    }
```

Comment: this works fine providing each line has a closing parentheses ")"